# Getting from Lille to Paris by public transport, after 10pm

Tags: trains, public-transport, france, paris, lille

I've been looking at train times from Lille to Paris, and was rather surprised to discover that the last train back is very early. On Monday-Saturday it leaves Lille at 21:51, and gets into Paris at 23:11. (There's a slightly later train on a Sunday, 22:13 to 23:17). After that, there's nothing until about 6am.

Are there any other public transport options to get from Lille to Paris later at night? I'm ideally after something around midnight, but general options for late night would be helpful. Are there any other options to take once the trains stop?

Comment: On most days, there's a Eurolines bus that leaves Lille just after seven, arriving at around 10. :)

Comment: yeah indeed the big problem of trains in France is that they are planned to arrive at the latest around midnight. So whatever the length of your trip, you should always plan your departure according to it (for me the latest train to go see my family is at 6pm, the trip lasting 4 hours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three realistic options to go from Lille to Paris: train, bus and car. If the trains aren't running at a time you want to travel, I don't think you'll find a bus either. Both [Eurolines](http://www.eurolines.fr/fr/) and [Idbus](http://www.idbus.co.uk/schedule/21881) have even more restricted schedules than the train. The non-profit [APTA](http://www.lilletransport.com/Lille-Paris-en-bus.html?lang=fr) won't help you with their two buses a day. It's just barely possible that there is some international bus between Benelux and Southern France that goes through Lille and Paris, but they'd typically be avoiding the cities and not taking passengers.

That leaves renting a car or hitch-hiking. There are several sites where you can find a driver looking for someone to ride with him and share the costs, such as [Allostop](http://www.allostop.net/) and [Covoiturage.com](http://www.covoiturage.com/) (note: this is not a recommendation, I've never used either service).